# two apparently same methods giving different results flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

Im trying to work with message flashing with flask and also trying to gain a better understanding of Flask_SQLAlchemy and SQL as a whole.
I'm trying to get a message to appear if the user enters an incorrect email address i have managed to find a solution that works but am confused why a similar solution doesn't.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    email = request.form.get("email")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if not user:
            flash("sorry that email doesn't exist")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        elif not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            flash("Password inccorect pleasew try again")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('secrets', id=user.id))
    return render_template("login.html")
```

This code works perfectly fine and i am getting the error message pop up as expected however when i adjust the
`user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()` to
`user = db.session.execute(db.select(User).filter_by(email=email)).scalar_one()`
so the block of code looks like this..

```
@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    email = request.form.get("email")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = db.session.execute(db.select(User).filter_by(email=email)).scalar_one()
        if not user:
            flash("sorry that email doesn't exist")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        elif not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            flash("Password incorrect please try again")
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('secrets', id=user.id))
    return render_template("login.html")
```

then the code throws the following error

```
raise exc.NoResultFound(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoResultFound: No row was found when one was required
```

i'm aware that this error is being raised because the database entry isn't being found, but from reading the documentation i've been led to believe that there is no distinction between using the two methods and that the `db.session.execute(db.select())` is just an updated version of `User.query` and so far i've been able to use both interchangeably throughout my code without any issues.

Does anybody know exactly how these two methods differ if there is a difference at all and why i'm getting different results with what i believe to be two lines of code that are basically doing the same thing, or is the problem with my code and are these two methods interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.CursorResult.scalar_one)  `scalar_one` returns an object if there is one or raises an exception if there are no results or more than one.
What you want is probably `scalar_one_or_none`. Alternatively you may use try/except block instead of the `if` check.

Comment: For some reason a try except block wasn’t working properly with the Flask flash method I was trying to use, it did however stop the error, but I found the desired result using .first(). Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out. I did try numerous if and try statements and was still getting errors. What I needed to do was to use `.first()` instead of `.scalar-one()`.